# Custom placeholder in input with icon

Tags: css

I am trying to make a custom placeholder for my "Search" input. It should look like a search icon (using Bootstrap `glyphicon glyphicon-search` classes for that) and then the word "Search", inside the input element, just as a placeholder looks like, and centered.

I am trying to position the `div` containing these to elements inside the input but I can't get it right.

Here's the code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83x8tfwp/).

HTML:

```
<div class="search-wrapper">
    <form class="post_search" id="post_search" action="/posts/explore" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
        <input autocomplete="off" class="search-input" type="search" name="q[caption_or_user_user_name_cont]" id="q_caption_or_user_user_name_cont">
        <div class="placeholder">
            <div>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                <span>Search</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.search-wrapper {
  max-width: 340px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline;
}

.search-wrapper .search-input {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 220px;
  height: 31px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  transition: 0.25s all;
}

.search-wrapper .search-input:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.25s all;
}

.search-wrapper .placeholder {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Then when focusing on the input the placeholder should be gone, I guess this shouldn't be difficult with some js.

But back to the issue, what am I doing wrong? How can I display the placeholder as intented?

Comment: I already want to mention that because of how your elements are positioned, you don't even need javascript, just target with `input:focus + .placeholder`

Comment: Sorry but I am not familiar with snippets... You have the code in jsfiddle, which is close enough to my working example. And you're right, I can target it that way and add the `display: none` property. Anyway, that is NOT what I am asking.

Comment: Wanna try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/83x8tfwp/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/83x8tfwp/6/

HTML:

```
<div class="search-wrapper">
    <form class="post_search" id="post_search" action="/posts/explore" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
        <input autocomplete="off" class="search-input" type="search" name="q[caption_or_user_user_name_cont]" id="q_caption_or_user_user_name_cont">
        <div class="placeholder">
            <div>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                <span>Search</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.search-wrapper {
  max-width: 280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  color: #aaa;
}

.search-wrapper .search-input {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 220px;
  height: 31px;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  transition: 0.25s all;
}

.search-wrapper .search-input:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.25s all;
}

.search-wrapper .search-input:focus + .placeholder {
  display: none;
}

.search-wrapper .placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 38%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.placeholder').on('click', function() {
    $('.search-input').focus();
});

if ($('.search-input').val()) {
    $('.placeholder').hide();
}

$('.search-input').on('blur', function() {
    if (!$('.search-input').val()) {
        $('.placeholder').show();
    }
});

$('.search-input').on('focus', function() {
    if (!$('.search-input').val()) {
        $('.placeholder').hide();
    }
});

$('.search-input').on('input', function() {
    if ($('.search-input').val()) {
        $('.placeholder').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not simplify this *enormously*? You already *have* the `placeholder` built into HTML! Here's what you can do:

```css
input[type="search"]::-webkit-input-placeholder:before {
  content: "\e003  ";
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}

input[type="search"]:-moz-placeholder:before {
  content: "\e003  ";
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

input[type="search"]::-moz-placeholder:before {
  content: "\e003  ";
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}

input[type="search"]:-ms-input-placeholder:before {  
  content: "\e003  ";
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}
```

```html
<input type='search' placeholder='search here' />
```

Now don't be worried, **the icon isn't displaying here because I haven't included font-awesome** (or whatever the `Glyphicons Halflings` font is provided by), but this makes it tremendously simply to create a nice placeholder. It even works like one! It also reduces your code greatly, although browser support is a little less stellar (it really depends how far back you want to go).

Font Awesome uses the unicode glyphs and a font with all those icons included, so as long as you use the right font and copy in the correct character into your `content` property, this will work.

*this was tested in Safari and Chrome*

Comment: if I do this how could I hide the placeholder when focusing in the input?

Comment: It does this automatically!

Comment: lol yeah right, I guess I will rather do this because using the div if you click on it you don't get focused in the input. Any way to center the placeholder?

Comment: Not sure. Does `text-align: center` work..? I do want to mention that not all browser support this. I couldn't get it working on FF tbh...